# Keep messing up percentage change depending on multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, percentage

Once again I go to you, the great stackoverflow community, for help. I posted this question more than once but somehow I'm not capable of solving this seamingly simple problem... Honestly, I'm getting a little frustrated here, so eternal gratitude for all who'll help me with this.

Multiple similar answers on stack overflow worked on my small reproducible data frame but when I used the same tactics on my original one it didn't work. So first a little translation of the variables (they're in Dutch):

- `Gemeente` == municipality
- `jaar` == year
- `Beleidscode` ~ crime category
- `aantal_misdrijven` == number of offences
- We won't need `Kennisnamedatum` == (date) and `weekdag` == weekday for this problem.

My problem:

I want to calculate change from `2017` opposed to `2015` grouped by `Gemeente` and `Beleidscode`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# This wil download my original data frame with ease:
df <- read_csv("https://github.com/thomasdebeus/colourful-facts/raw/master/projects/crime_dataset.csv")

# The following tries to first add a column with totals per 
# year, municipality and crime category. Then calculate percentage change.

df %>%
  group_by(Gemeente, jaar, Beleidscode) %>%
  arrange(Gemeente, jaar, Beleidscode) %>%
  summarise(per_jaar_Gem_misdrijf = sum(aantal_misdrijven)) %>%
  mutate(perct_change = (per_jaar_gem_misdrijf - lag(per_jaar_gem_misdrijf, order_by = jaar)) / lag(per_jaar_gem_misdrijf, order_by = jaar))
  ungroup()
```

So yeah, as you might accpect this isn't creating the right figures...
I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to calculate the percentage change from the previous year.  One way you can do this is

```
library(tidyverse)

# This wil download my original data frame with ease:
df <- read_csv("https://github.com/thomasdebeus/colourful-facts/raw/master/projects/crime_dataset.csv")

# Create a data frame with the summary count by year
dfSumByYear <-
  df %>%
  group_by(Gemeente, jaar, Beleidscode) %>%
  summarise(per_jaar_Gem_misdrijf = sum(aantal_misdrijven)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Add the Previous Year counts as an additional column
dfSumByYearWithPrev <-
  dfSumByYear %>% 
  left_join(dfSumByYear %>% 
              mutate(JaarJoin = jaar+1) %>% 
              rename(per_PrevJaar_Gem_misdrijf = per_jaar_Gem_misdrijf) %>% 
              select(-jaar), by = c("Gemeente", c("jaar"="JaarJoin"), "Beleidscode")) %>% 
  # Calculate the Percentage Change
  mutate(perct_change = (coalesce(per_jaar_Gem_misdrijf,0L) - coalesce(per_PrevJaar_Gem_misdrijf,0L)) / coalesce(per_PrevJaar_Gem_misdrijf,0L))
```

If you want to calculate the change from 2015 to 2017 specifically, one way you can do this is

```
library(tidyverse)

# This wil download my original data frame with ease:
df <- read_csv("https://github.com/thomasdebeus/colourful-facts/raw/master/projects/crime_dataset.csv")

# Calculate the percentage change from 2015 to 2017
df %>%
  group_by(Gemeente, jaar, Beleidscode) %>%
  summarise(per_jaar_Gem_misdrijf = sum(aantal_misdrijven)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(jaar, per_jaar_Gem_misdrijf, fill = 0L) %>% 
  mutate(perct_change = (`2017` - `2015`) / `2015`)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer although `spread(jaar, per_jaar_Gem_misdrijf, fill = 0L)` is causing weird values. I don't have any `NA` values in my data frame and setting `fill = 0L` is masking that `spread()` function is misinterpreting the data...